# Getting the Root Address of the environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to get the root URL of a rails application from the config folder? Also, can you get the port on which the server is running?

Comment: Where would you like to call it?

Comment: @user2503775  From the `config\initializers` directory

Answer (score 0):

In your **database.yml**:

```
development:
    adapter: mysql
    encoding: utf8
    database: db_development
    host: https://example.com
    port: XXX
    username: root
    password:
```

And then, call it from **config\initializers**:

```
require "yaml"
config = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config","database.yml"))[Rails.env]
config["port"] => XXX
config["host"] => https://example.com
```

Comment: This doesn't help: every time I upload to Heroku, the port number changes.